# Docker Desktop shows error on Windows; It looks like there is an error with Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-desktop

Windows 10 (19043.1889)
Docker Desktop 4.11.1

I installed docker but it showed "It looks like there is an error with Docker Desktop, restart it to fix it" when opening [Settings] page
I couldn't change any params in [Settings]; I can check some configurations but [Apply & Restart] button didn't enabled.

Several times I tried uninstall & install, but nothing changed.
Docker itself worked, but because of error, I couldn't change resources spec.

I wonder if someone has any idea

Thank you

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/overview/#self-diagnose-tool — please attach self-check

Comment: I got vpnkit.exe is not running, but it seem not root cause, because other machine it worked well also got same message